# How do I add a column to my derived classes with STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, single-table-inheritance

I already have single table inheritance set up, with the type column in my `form_field` model and my `number_field` and `text_field` classes inheriting from the `form_field`.

Consider the following (when I fire up `rails console`):

```
2.1.1 :001 > nf = NumberField.new
 => #<NumberField id: nil, label: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, type: "NumberField"> 
2.1.1 :002 > nf.is_a? FormField
 => true
```

I tried the following migration(s):

```
class AddInputToNumberFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :number_fields, :input, :integer
  end
end
```

However, when I run `rake db:migrate`, the console complains saying I can't add the column because `:number_fields` is not a table (STI so the table is `:form_fields`).

I've looked around for quite a while, but no SO question or Google link explains it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add columns to the base class of your STI table. If `NumberField` inherits from `FormField`, then add the columns to `form_fields`. You've basically answered your own question by observing this.

Remember STI stands for "**Single Table** Inheritance" so there is only one table that can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Add the column to the STI table :form_fields

```
class AddInputToNumberFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :form_fields, :input, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: I have another class called `text_field`. Will this affect the input column in that class? I want that input to be of `string` type.

Comment: And how will Rails know I want this to be particular to `NumberField`?

Comment: It will not be particular to NumberField.  You are using STI, so the underlying table is used for all models that derive from your STI base class.